# Printing out Main Category ID's in a Loop

Tags: categories

I'm looking to print out All of the Main Categories (So Exclude Sub-Categories) in a Loop, I need to get the ID's to do some advanced category listings.

So I need to echo this out:

```
3 CatName
4 CatName
5 CatName
x CatName
```

Where the number is the category # and the CatName is the name of the category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

example:

```
<?php 
foreach(get_categories('parent=0&orderby=id') as $cat) { 
   echo $cat->term_id.' '.$cat->name.'<br/>'; 
} 
?>
```